# How can i put a conditional statement in order to validate the view of FloatingActionButton in a scaffold based on a usertype in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am just struggling to validate a FloatingActionButton using one with a ternary operator and if statement .here is the code

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  key: key,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('profile list'),
    flexibleSpace: header(),
  ),
  body: FutureBuilder<List<Leave>>(
    future: fetchLeave(http.Client()),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? profileListView(leave: snapshot.data)         //using this class variable 
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  ),
  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ProfileForm(),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

hence in order to validate it with a userType as a **student /teacher /admin** I need to put the FloatingActionButton in a conditional statement. so as I have tried one.

```
floatingActionButton:
      (profileListView().leave[0].userdetails.userType == "student")    //using the variable of another class
          ? new FloatingActionButton(
              //other codes
            )
          : new FloatingActionButton(
              //other codes
            ),
```

But it is calling the function at NULL

[image: Error PIC]

please help me to solve this error...

### profileListView()

```
class ProfileListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Leave> leave;                 //fetching this variable
   
  const ProfileListView({Key key, this.leave}) : super(key: key);
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
     //other codes

   }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is profileListView? a widget?

Comment: Please provide more information, as we do not know what you profileListView is. I assume that the snapshot data in your body is null and so the caller [] is called on null

Comment: I have mentioned the required class, and yes after adding the condition in the floatingActionButton it seems to show the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`profileListView().leave` is null because you create a new instance of `profileListView`.
To obtain the `leave` list in your FloatingActionButton you can wrap entire Scaffold with FutureBuilder instead of just its `body` parameter:

```dart
Widget build(...) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: fetchLeave(...),
    builder: (context, snaphot) => Scaffold(
      body: snapshot.hasData ? ... : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      floatingActionButton: snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data[0]... ? 
        FloatingActionButton(...) : 
        null,
    ),
  );
}
```

This way, your body and button will always have access to the same, synchronized state.